# Svg horizontal line between background

Tags: javascript, html, svg, size

```css
.left-wave-container {
  line-height: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<div className="left-wave-container">

    <div className="svg-container">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1280" height="430" viewBox="0 0 1280 430"><path d="M0,465V35A96.575,96.575,0,0,0,.64,46.15,94.294,94.294,0,0,0,2.56,56.94C15.71,112.271,78.9,153.52,171,186.521v.159c116.77,41.85,280,70.44,446.67,97.681,6,1,12,2,18,2.93C682.9,295,730.32,302.6,776.9,310.43c3.73.61,7.45,1.25,11.16,1.87,2.72.46,5.431.93,8.131,1.37l7.59,1.291,2.05.35c5.07.869,10.139,1.74,15.179,2.62C890.64,330,957.62,342.71,1018.56,357c5.45,1.29,10.86,2.569,16.21,3.88q13.49,3.28,26.54,6.7,7.53,2,14.9,4l1.2.329c5.65,1.53,11.2,3.1,16.691,4.691,1.2.329,2.36.68,3.54,1,81,23.559,145.33,51.53,182.08,86.95l.28.26V465Z" transform="translate(0 -35)" fill="#2196f3"/>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div className="container">
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to put together one svg header with a wave with the same background color that it has but in the bottom in specifics viewport sizes one line is displayed between them.

One curious things is, when I don't alter the width of height in the CSS or directly in the svg the horizontal line disappear but it just has the size ah the beggining, no the full viewport (I realize this when I upload the snippet).

Thanks for read!

Comment: So the linked image is the expected result?

Comment: put up a snippet. it helps

Comment: @joyBlanks I do believe you are viewing the wrong post. If you aren't, please tell me where the snippet is. :)

Comment: @Rojo I was letting the OP know if he/she can put up a snippet working code so users can look at it, its just a image, a snippet will tell if there is a prob with svg itself or where the line coming from

Comment: @Rojo @ joyBlanks I already update the post, I forgot the SVG file. Thanks for answer!

Comment: @lpluispacheco Check here in an hour, I'll try to make an answer

Comment: @Alexandr_TT I'll be here, thanks!!

Comment: @joyBlanks oops, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drew your wave in `Inkscape`

Removed SVG from the markup `width =" 1280"` `height ="430"`

Now the application will be adaptive at any screen resolution.

Styles did not work because there was `<div className =" container ">`

write `<div class =" container ">` correctly

```css
.left-wave-container {
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 0 !important;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-wave-container">

    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   viewBox="0 0 1280 430">
   <path d="m2.7 20.4c-1.2-35.4-1.3 4.9 17.7 35.5 19.1 30.6 57.4 52.9 91.9 68.1 130.2 56.1 261.7 80.2 377.8 101.5 187.9 32.6 388.1 61.4 560.4 103 39.4 9.7 74.8 18.1 117.1 33.6 37.9 13.9 135.6 67.5 100.7 67.1C995.4 425.3 1.6 425.3 1.6 425.3c0 0 2.1-377.7 1.2-404.9z" transform="translate(0 5)"  fill="#2196f3" stroke="#2196f3" stroke-width="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I didn't think in just let the SVG select the height and width sizes. The only solution that I had was set in specific viewports the height but isn't the proper way. 

Thanks @Alexandr_TT and the rest that comment!

Cheers!

Comment: @lpluispacheco  Check - the layout looks different in FF and Chrome / is not visible in Chrome under svg  the bottom blue block

Comment: Yes, I check this, in FF a couple of sizes the horizontal line appears in the bottom, there's a way to fix it in FF? i.e: If I select the height in CSS the horizontal line doesn't appear never, the only thing is just that I've to add the height for the different breakpoints for the responsive but works in both explorers FF & chrome.

Comment: @lpluispacheco Browsers sometimes render the same layout in different ways, especially when it is related to adaptability. There are uncorrected bugs in any browser. Therefore, you must always seek a compromise.  Try using `flex` and` grid` in the layout

Comment: I tried with flex, multiples ways but seems to not be compatible anyway, at least no in the ways that I tried.

The only way to be compatible in the rest of browsers is taking off the width and height like you told me and in the css assign values, I hope these information could help someone as well, thanks again Alex.

Cheers!